Missing Information with Web Scraping
I want to try to divide my music files into folders divided by genre, and for ease I'm writing the code in c#. The information I need is in this div class of the html code of the google page "xGj8Mb", but using the standard c# method and also the AngleSharp library, I can't access this information and it doesn't save much other info. I rewrote the same code in Java using the Jsoup library and it takes every information from the page. Below I report the code I used to do this experiment, both using AngleSharp and the standard method.
Code using standard method
public class Program {
private static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    const string folderPath = @"C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Attilio\ATTILIO MUSIC";
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("DOES NOT EXIST");
        return;
    }

    var archive = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
    foreach (var entry in archive) {
        // Check if the file is not a directory and has the .mp3 or .wav extension
        var fileName = entry.Split(folderPath + @"\")[1];
        //Console.WriteLine(fileName);

        SearchOnInternet(fileName);
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Number: {archive.Length}");
}

private static void SearchOnInternet(string fileName) {
    // Split to remove the extension from the file name
    if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        fileName = fileName.Split(".mp3")[0];
    else if (fileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
        fileName = fileName.Split(".wav")[0];

    // Conversion for the search
    var fileNameAsUrl = Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine(fileNameAsUrl);
    var url =
        $"https://www.google.com/search?q={fileNameAsUrl}";

    // Search
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var response = client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var responseBody = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Save page
            var outputPath = @"C:\Users\chris\Documents\Universita\Programmi\C#\FileAura\FileAuraServer\Search";
            if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
            File.WriteAllText(
                @$"{outputPath}\{fileName}.html",
                responseBody.Result);
        }
    }
}

}
Code using AngleSharp
private static async void SearchOnInternet(string fileName) {
    // Split to remove the extension from the file name
    if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        fileName = fileName.Split(".mp3")[0];
    else if (fileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
        fileName = fileName.Split(".wav")[0];

    // Conversion for the search
    var fileNameAsUrl = Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName);
    var googleSearchUrl =
        $"https://www.google.com/search?q={fileNameAsUrl}";

    // Create an HttpClient to send the request
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // Send a GET request to Google
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(googleSearchUrl);

    // Ensure the request was successful
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Get the response content as a string
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Save the HTML content to a file
    string filePath = "output.html";
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(filePath, responseContent);

    Console.WriteLine($"The HTML content has been saved to {filePath}");

    // Configure AngleSharp to parse the HTML
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
    var parser = context.GetService<IHtmlParser>();
    var document = await parser.ParseDocumentAsync(responseContent);

    // Example: extract the title of the search results page
    var title = document.Title;
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + title);

    // Example: extract the search results
    var results = document.QuerySelectorAll("h3"); // <h3> elements contain the titles of the search results

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.TextContent);
    }
}

This are the page that I want

This is the page that I receive from that code


Please [edit] your question, and add more info about "Missing Information" Which info is missing, and include a specific URL to make this a [mre].

This question is similar to: HttpClient - Different content returned than browser. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  (and Please stop posting huge images without explaining what has to be seen there....)

If you write in c# why the  jsoup tag?

I'm using JetBrains Rider as IDE

You should at least add one URL you are trying to fetch. One sanity check would be to dumping the web page using wget, and then loading such local file into a browser. If the content is not to your liking it means you have to figure out how to make server to return more info (like passing agent info). So this preliminary check has nothing to do with C#. Side-note -- it would be useful to improve your C# code, this is in turn would improve quality of your question.
